# How to correct error after installation?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 17.01 I chose the option: Delete disk and install Ubuntu.
Following the instructions that appear in the questions of the askubuntu partners for different previous problems:
[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
I followed the steps until I got to number 13, when running:

`sudo su;
efi="/target/boot/efi/EFI"; \
if [[ -e "${efi}/boot" ]]; then \
  echo "Backup:"; \
  mv -v "${efi}/boot/" "${efi}/boot-bak-$(lsb_release -cs)"; \
fi; \
echo "Copy:"; \
cp -va "${efi}/ubuntu" "${efi}/boot"; \
arch="$(ls -1 {efi}/ubuntu/shim*.efi)"; \
arch="${arch#*shim}"; \
arch="${arch%.efi}"; \
cp -v "${efi}/boot/shim${arch}.efi" "${efi}/boot/boot${arch}.efi";`

the console shows me the following:

`cp: I can not perform`stat 'in' / target / boot / efi / EFI / ubuntu ': the file or directory does not exist
ls: can not access '{efi} /ubuntu/shim*.efi': the file or directory does not exist.
cp: can not perform `stat 'in' /target/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi ': there is no file or directory`

When running fdisk -l the result is:

`/dev/sda1     EFI System
/dev/sda2     Linux filesystem`

When updating to Ubuntu 18.04 the screen remains black and I run out of operating system.
I imagine that this must be due to how you perform the installation.
How can I correct the following error that arises when running the indicated commands and be able to update?

`cp: I can not perform`stat 'in' / target / boot / efi / EFI / ubuntu ': the file or directory does not exist
ls: can not access '{efi} /ubuntu/shim*.efi': the file or directory does not exist.
cp: can not perform `stat 'in' /target/boot/efi/EFI/boot/shim.efi ': there is no file or directory`

I do not know how to ask the question so they can help me, they are several days trying without success, and I always ask the question badly.

Thank you.